# Making a visual basic spinner control update the linked cell value

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I've added a spinner control to a visual basic userform. I've linked the spinner control to a cell in my spreadsheet.   When I show the userform and click the spinner the value in the link cell does not update unless I click another element on the userfomr.

Is there a way to update the linked cell value with each click of the spinner without having to change focus off the spinner and onto another element.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Seeing some code would be nice....

Comment: Perhaps that's the problem.  At thip point the only code I have is a calculate command on the change property and I've defined the control source in the spinners property both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Private Sub SpinButton1_SpinDown()
 Range("A1") = Range("A1") - 1
End Sub

Private Sub SpinButton1_SpinUp()
 Range("A1") = Range("A1") + 1
End Sub
```

Or whatever increment you want